# Agrupar de 4 en 4 en Java

Tags: java

quiero agrupar los elementos de 4 en 4 en java.

Cada pregunta tiene 4 subpreguntas, por tanto esas 4 subpreguntas le pertenecen.

```
                 String[] preguntas = request.getParameterValues("pregunta[]");
                 String[] subpreguntas = request.getParameterValues("subpregunta[]");

                int i = 0;

                //Recorro todas las sub preguntas.
                for (int j = 0; j < subpreguntas.length; j++) {

                    //Cada pregunta tiene 4 subpreguntas, por tanto hay que agrupar.
                    if (j % 4 == 0) {
                        co.Insertar_Sub_pregunta(i, subpreguntas[j]);

                    } else {
                        co.Insertar_pregunta(i, preguntas[i]);
                        i++;
                    }

                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inserta bien las preguntas, pero no las subpreguntas, además yo no tengo el id de preguntas en 3 , ¿ pueden ayudarme para agrupar en 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que se donde está el error. En `if(j % 4 == 0){` solo entrará cuando `j` sea múltiplo de 4 (0, 4, 8...), es decir, solo se añadirá 1 **subpregunta** de cada grupo de 4. En su lugar, deberías de añadir una **pregunta** cada 4 subpreguntas:

```
int i = -1; //Empiezo en -1 para que en la primera iteración se ponga a 0.
//Recorro todas las sub preguntas.
for(int j = 0; j < subpreguntas.length; j++){
    //Cada pregunta tiene 4 subpreguntas, por tanto hay que agrupar.
    if(j % 4 == 0){
        i++;
        co.Insertar_pregunta(i, preguntas[i]);//Se añade la pregunta.
    }//No se necesita else
    co.Insertar_Sub_pregunta(i, subpreguntas[j]);
}
```

No se el código del objeto `co`. En este caso primero se añade 1 pregunta y después sus 4 respuestas. Si funciona de otro modo, realiza los cambios que encuentres oportunos.

Comment: co es para insertar,no te preocupes, sin el else , las preguntas[i] se sale del array, porque hay más subpreguntas que preguntas.

Comment: Lo he corregido, ahora debería de servir.

Comment: perfecto , llevaba horas atascado XD